# class method __instancecheck__ does not work

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7.3 on Windows. I tried to override the `__instancecheck__` magic method as a class method. But I can not make it work.

```
class Enumeration(int):
    @classmethod
    def __instancecheck__(cls, inst):
        if type(inst) == cls:
            return True
        if isinstance(inst, int) and inst in range(0,10):
            return True
        return False

print isinstance(1, Enumeration)   # prints False
print isinstance(1, Enumeration()) # prints True
```

I assume the first print statement would get True. But it seems the magic method `__instancecheck__` is not called. And I don't know why the second print statement can work since the `isinstance` should take a class/type as the second parameter.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`instancecheck` must be defined in a metaclass:

```
class Enumeration(type):
    def __instancecheck__(self, other):
        print 'hi'
        return True


class EnumInt(int):
    __metaclass__ = Enumeration

print isinstance('foo', EnumInt) # prints True
```

Why is that? For the same reason why your second example worked. When python evaluates `isinstance(A, B)` it assumes `B` to be an object, looks for its class  and calls `__instancecheck__` on that class:

```
isinstance(A, B):
    C = class-of(B)
    return C.__instancecheck__(A)
```

But when `B` is a class itself, then its class `C` should be a class of a class, in other words, a meta-class!

Comment: can't reproduce this in python 3

Comment: For Python 3 you have to use `class EnumInt(int, metaclass=Enumeration)`

Answer (score 8):

The docs say:

> Note that these methods are looked up on the type (metaclass) of a class. They cannot be defined as class methods in the actual class. This is consistent with the lookup of special methods that are called on instances, only in this case the instance is itself a class.

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks

Comment: Thank you. @thg435 gave me a good example and now I know how to achieve this.