# Why __instancecheck__ is not always called depending on argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is this code:

```
class Meta(type):
  def __instancecheck__(self, instance):
    print("__instancecheck__")
    return True

class A(metaclass=Meta):
  pass


a = A()
isinstance(a, A) # __instancecheck__ not called
isinstance([], A) # __instancecheck__ called
```

Why `__instancecheck__` is called for `[]` argument but not for `a` argument?

Comment: this is related to (but not a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135712/class-method-instancecheck-does-not-work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PyObject_IsInstance` does a quick test for exact match.

[`Objects/abstract.c`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/abstract.c):

```
int
PyObject_IsInstance(PyObject *inst, PyObject *cls)
{
    static PyObject *name = NULL;

    /* Quick test for an exact match */
    if (Py_TYPE(inst) == (PyTypeObject *)cls)
        return 1;
// ...
```

---

don't like the fast path? you can try this (at your own risk):

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> def isinstance(a, b):
...     class tmp(type(a)):
...          pass
...     return __builtin__.isinstance(tmp(), b)
... 
>>> __builtin__.isinstance(a, A)
True
>>> isinstance(a, A)
__instancecheck__
True
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that the PEP describing `__instancecheck__()` is faulty.  PEP 3119 says:

> The primary mechanism proposed here is to allow overloading the
>   built-in functions isinstance() and issubclass(). The overloading
>   works as follows: The call isinstance(x, C) first checks whether
>   `C.__instancecheck__` exists, and if so, calls `C.__instancecheck__(x)`
>   instead of its normal implementation.

You can write:

```
class C:
    def do_stuff(self):
        print('hello')

C.do_stuff(C())
```

So based on the quote above from the PEP, you should be able to write

```
class C:
    @classmethod
    def __instancecheck__(cls, x):
        print('hello')


C.__instancecheck__(C())

--output:--
hello
```

But isinstance() does not call that method:

```
class C:
    @classmethod
    def __instancecheck__(cls, y):
        print('hello')


x = C()
isinstance(x, C)

--output:--
<nothing>
```

The PEP then goes on to say:

> These methods are intended to be be called on classes whose metaclass
>   is (derived from) ABCMeta...

Okay, let's try that:

```
import abc

class MyMeta(abc.ABCMeta):  #A metaclass derived from ABCMeta
    def __instancecheck__(cls, inst):
        print('hello')
        return True

class C(metaclass=MyMeta):  #A class whose metaclass is derived from ABCMeta
    pass


x = C()
C.__instancecheck__(x)

--output:--
hello
```

But once again isinstance() does not call that method:

```
isinstance(x, C)

--output:--
<nothing>
```

Conclusion: PEP 3119 needs to be rewritten--along with the "Data Model" docs.