# Can a user-defined class be made to conditionally test as an instance of another class?

Tags: python, class, instance, python-3.3

By defining the `__instancecheck__()` special method of a class's metaclass, one can control when an object tests as a member of that class. What if you have a predefined class P (say, a builtin class) and you want to conditionally control whether a given instance of your class C tests as an object of type P? Can this be done?

Here is a silly example:

```
class C:
    def __init__ (self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Suppose I want C to test as an object of class `numbers.Number`, but only if `x > y` and `y % 3 == 0`. (I said it would be a silly example.)

```
from numbers import Number
assert isinstance(C(4, 3), Number)
assert not isinstance(C(1, 3), Number)
assert not isinstance(C(4, 2), Number)
```

Can this be done? How?

Comment: possible duplicate of [class method \_\_instancecheck\_\_ does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135712/class-method-instancecheck-does-not-work)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of that other question. The two questions are qualitatively different.

Comment: I don't know what you're really trying to do, but it seems more reasonable to have a factory function that returns either a `C_Number` instance (which "is" a numbers.Number) or a `C_NotNumber` instance (which "is not" a numbers.Number).  The is-a-number property would then be static, but given that "normal" numbers are immutable, that seems like a sensible restriction.

Comment: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `__instancecheck__()` is defined on the class you want to test intances against -- in this case, the class `numbers.Number`.  This class uses `abc.ABCMeta` as its metaclass (see the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/72c7a4cd4f55/Lib/numbers.py#l13)).  The mechanism `ABCMeta` provides to add further classes that should be considered instances of the class is the [`register()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register).  To achieve exactly what you asked for, you would have to replace the metaclass of `numbers.Number` by some custom subclass of `ABCMeta` that overrides `__instancecheck__()` to provide the functionality you want.  This would be possible in CPython by assigning a new class to `numbers.Number.__class__`, but this wouldn't be guaranteed to work in other python implementations.

```
import abc
import numbers

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def is_number(self):
        return self.x > self.y and not self.y % 3

class NumberMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
    def __instancecheck__(self, obj):
        if type(obj) is C:
            return obj.is_number()
        return abc.ABCMeta.__instancecheck__(obj)

numbers.Number.__class__ = NumberMeta

assert isinstance(C(4, 3), Number)
assert not isinstance(C(1, 3), Number)
assert not isinstance(C(4, 2), Number)
```

That said, actually doing something like this seems a terrible idea.  Why do you think you need this?